# Comparing the rate of admitting to not quitting smoking between two groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

One group of patients was interviewed by doctors and 2% patients admitted to smoking. Another group of patients was interviewed by nurses and their admittance rate to smoking was 10%.

How would I show that the difference in rates is statistically significant?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are comparing the rates of quitting as much as the admittance of not quitting.

Comment: Thankyou so much zbicyclist. Let me clarify. I am comparing the admittance rate reported to doctor and then the nurse. After comparison and analysis we will try to analyses the reasons of differences between these two groups. Second thing we want to compare is the doctor offers patient nicotine replacement therapy and the nurse offers patient that same thing. We found out that patients accept nicotine replacement therapy more from the nurses. Now we want to compare that rate as well and analyse it, thanks

Comment: Is your sample paired? Another words, does a patient first answer the smoke question for the doctor then the nurse?

Comment: To expand on @RioRaider 's question, if it is paired, is the order doctor->nurse (or nurse->doctor) followed for all patients, or does it vary?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the patients are random, independent samples for each group, consider a 2-proportion z-test where:

$$z=(\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2)/SE$$
$$SE = \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})(1/n_1)+(1/n_2)}$$
$$\hat{p}=(\hat{p}_1*n_1+\hat{p}_2*n_2)/(n_1+n_2)$$

Or is your sample paired?

A potential solution for paired samples is [McNemar's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test).

Comment: Thankyou, It is the same 1200 patients. Doctor-> Nurse order

Comment: The other thing that we are looking at is, once a patient admits to smoking she (we are only considering pregnant mothers) is referred to quit smoking clinic. In the quit smoking clinic- 1-How many admit to second hand smoking, 2-For first hand smoking how many agree to intervention that is nicotine replacement therapy, 3-For second hand smoking how many agree to intervention that is nicotine replacement therapy, 4 What is the quit rate for first hand smokers?, 5-What is the quit rate for second hand smokers?

Comment: 6-In the women who use nicotine replacement therapy do their babies do better than ones who refuse nicotine replacement therapy? (subgroup analysis), thanks

Comment: @sairahsharif It is generally poor practice to put additional questions in comments. I recommend you formally ask your additional [questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  You can reference this question in new questions.

Comment: @sairahsharif Since it's the same 1200 patients, RioRaider's suggestion about McNemar's test seems right. If you have trouble with figuring out that reference, let us know. If you can fill in the 2x2 (i.e. how many people said yes to both doctor and nurse, yes to doctor no to nurse, no to doctor yes to nurse, and no to both) I'd be happy to check your calculations.  BUT not that since the order is always doctor-> nurse you are testing multiple things at the same time.  Still worth analyzing.

Answer (score 0):

@sairahsharif  You have 6 more questions. I think what you have is the following design:

A: said yes to doctor, yes to nurse

B: said yes to doctor, no to nurse

C: said no to doctor, yes to nurse

D: said no to doctor, no to nurse

and for question 1 "1-How many admit to second hand smoking" the answers can be either "admit" or "don't admit".

I'd approach this as a 4x2 chi-square.  Depending on the size of the cells, you may not have enough (too many expected values less than 5 can be a problem). But let's not deal with that problem until we know we have it.

I think for questions 2-5 the same thing works. Question 6 (do babies do better) you probably have a continuous measure rather than a yes/no measurement so a dummy variable regression would seem appropriate.  That may also make sense if people get multiple interventions and comply with some, but not all of them -- but I'd start with the question by question analysis first since it will be easier to understand.

Isn't there also a question 0: of those referred, how many actuallly show up?

I also have a question unrelated to statistical issues, just curiosity: what do you mean by "quitting secondary smoking"?

Comment: I meant second hand smoking, it means that people around you are smoking. I am trying to get the data set. It may take a week. Then I will contact you again.You have been very helpful, thanks